# Setting Flash Data When Session Expire Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, flash, session

What is the best way to set **flash data messages** when session have **timed out** and then be able to get message on login page.

I have a warning variable that would like to use but can not seem to get it working with sessions **timed out** I have it redirecting to the login page one sessions have timed out.

**But not sure best way to set flash data using my error array, any idea's.**

**Login Controller:**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Login extends MX_Controller {

   private $error = array();

   public function __construct() {
      parent::__construct();
      $this->load->library('user');
      $this->load->library('form_validation');
      $this->lang->load('common/login', 'english');
   } 

   public function index() {
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required|min_length[4]|max_length[12]');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|xss_clean');

      if($this->form_validation->run($this) == false) {

         $data['title'] = $this->lang->line('heading_title');

         $data['text_heading'] = $this->lang->line('text_heading');

         if (array_key_exists('warning', $this->error)) {
            $data['error_warning'] = $this->error['warning'];
         } else {
            $data['error_warning'] = '';
         }

         if (null !==($this->session->flashdata('message_name'), $this->error)) {
            $data['message'] = $this->session->set_flashdata('message_name', 'This is my message');
         } else {
            $data['message'] = '';
         }

         $this->load->view('common/login', $data);

      } else{ 

         if($this->validate()) {

             redirect('dashboard');

            } else {

               $data['title'] = $this->lang->line('heading_title');

               $data['text_heading'] = $this->lang->line('text_heading');

               if (array_key_exists('warning', $this->error)) {
                  $data['error_warning'] = $this->error['warning'];
               } else {
                  $data['error_warning'] = '';
               }

               if (null !==($this->session->flashdata('message_name'), $this->error)) {
                  $data['message'] = $this->session->set_flashdata('message_name', 'This is my message');
               } else {
                  $data['message'] = '';
               }

               $this->load->view('common/login', $data);

         }
      }
   }

   function validate() {
      $username = $this->input->post('username');
      $password = $this->input->post('password');

      if ($this->user->login($username, $password)) {
          return true;
      } else {
         $this->error['warning'] = $this->lang->line('error_login');
         return !$this->error;
      }
   }
}
```

**Login View**

```
<?php echo modules::run('common/header/index');?>

<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-8">
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading"><h2 class="panel-title"><i class="fa fa-key"></i> <?php echo $text_heading; ?></h2></div>
<div class="panel-body">

<?php if ($error_warning) { ?>
    <div class="alert alert-danger"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i> <?php echo $error_warning; ?>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
    </div>
<?php } ?>

<?php echo form_open('login');?>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> </span>
    <input type="text" name="username" value="" placeholder="Username"  class="form-control" size="50" />
    </div>
    <?php echo form_error('username', '<div class="text-danger">', '</div>'); ?>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></span>
        <input type="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="Password"  class="form-control"/>
        </div>
        <?php echo form_error('password', '<div class="text-danger">', '</div>'); ?>
    </div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="text-right">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-key"></i> Login</button>
    </div>
</div>

</form>

</div><!--/. Panel Body -->
</div><!--/. Panel Panel Default -->
</div>
</div>
</div>
<?php echo modules::run('common/footer/index');?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set_flshdat is codeigniter function that will only be available for next server request and then automatically cleared. you can see in detail here [flashdata](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html) and search for set_flashdata in this link

so if you need message after redirect to other page or same page

set flashdata on first requested controller page

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('message_name', 'This is my message');
```

and on second server request or your redirection page will get this flash data using below

```
echo $this->session->flashdata('message_name');
```

So, basically if you don't want to redirect page and want to load view

```
//set data in controller 
$data['message_name'] = 'This is my message'
//and pass this to view
$this->load->view('yourview_name', $data);
```

And in your view page just write

```
echo $message_name;
```